# Converting Array of Names to Linear Scale d3

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js

I have a set of data of a list of players. I want the color of the bars representing those players to be varied in a range of colors. The players names obviously are strings and not numbers...so somehow I need to say convert 16 players into a range from 0 to 1...so the first player would be closest to the first color in my array and the last player, to the last color in the array.

I have an example of colors and then I make a map of my players. I know I'm close but not quite there.

```
var colors = ["gray","green","yellow","red"];

    var dtMap = dt.map(function(d){
        return d.Player;
    })

// was trying something like this
//var playaExtent = d3.scale.linear().domain(d3.extent(dtMap)).range([0,1]);
// trying to make a linear scale
// out of some names which are mapped above

var heatmapColor = d3.scale.linear()
                   .domain(dtMap)
                   .range(colors);

.attr("fill", function(d) {
         console.log(d.Player)
         return heatmapColor(d.Player)})
```

Comment: I forgot to mention, currently the colors coming back is just a simple black.

Comment: Linear scale is not going to work for this. [`d3.scale.ordinal`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Ordinal-Scales#ordinal) is the thing to use here. Also, [`d3.scale.category20`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Ordinal-Scales#category20) may be handy.

Answer (score 0):

In the code below I'm using [polylinear scales](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales#linear_domain) to map 24 letters of the english alphabet to a range of four colors. The output (**[see demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qew98ps1/1/)**) produces a rainbow of colors while printing the letter and the hex notation of a number used for background fill.

Because we're working with the linear scale, the basic idea is to use alphabet array indexes as the domain and numerical representation of numbers for the range.

```
var colors = ['gray', 'green', 'yellow', 'red'],
    alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'],
    ratio = (alphabet.length - 1) / (colors.length - 1),
    scale = d3.scale.linear()
        // domain should be the same length as range in polylinear scales:
        .domain(colors.map(function (c, i) { return Math.round(i * ratio); }))
        // d3 automatically recognizes and interpolates color strings:
        .range(colors);

d3.select('#container').data(alphabet, function (d) { return d; })
    .enter().append('div')
        .text(function (d, i) { return d + ' ' + scale(i); })
        .style('background-color', function (d, i) { return scale(i); });
```

The number of colors and letters in the alphabet can be changed at will. In the case of 4 letters and 4 colors the program will output the exact mapping: gray "a", green "b", yellow "c", and a red "d".

Comment: I'm trying the above code...it still is registering black...and I think it's due to the fact I'm using the wrong return maybe? When I map to ordinal, it simply loops through the colors...and I want it to associate the colors with the first person in the data and 'fade' between them.

Comment: `code`.attr("fill", function(d) {
   console.log(d.Player)
      return heatmapColor(d.Player)})                         The console log is returning the player name just fine...I don't think it can associate it still with that new variable.

Comment: I guess I am not understanding what the difference between using d and i is in this case....I'm using d.Player which is the player value of the data.

Comment: The `i` (second argument) is the index of your player in the data array. You need to pass the index to the scale function.

Comment: OK, yea, I got it to work that way, which is a good start. The only issue now is that my players are arranged according to a different value and I want their colors to be arranged according to their name ( alphabetical )...In this case, it's assigning the first player with the highest value to the gray and the last player in the array ( which may not be the player with the lowest alphabetical value ) to the red. So a player with the name Andy would be gray and a player with the name Zack would be red but Zack could be first in the original array.

Comment: Well, just sort your array. What's the problem?